# Qt. Declare custom QEvent type ONCE

Tags: qt, qevent

I have a .h file with such code:

```
const QEvent::Type MyOnEventType =
           QEvent::Type(QEvent::registerEventType( QEvent::User + 500 ) );
```

This header uses twice in application. I found a problem that in different places MyOnEventType have different integer value. If make a break point on that code above, debugger stops 9 times.

Please help how to declare custom QEvent type ONCE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I'm understanding your question, but it sounds like you need to separate the declaration and the implementation. Something like:

**my_event.h**

```
class MyEvent : public QEvent {
 public:
  static const QEvent::Type MyEventType;
  // etc. 
};
```

**my_event.cpp**

```
#include "my_event.h"

const QEvent::Type MyEvent::MyEventType = 
        static_cast<QEvent::Type>(QEvent::registerEventType());

// etc.
```

Comment: How then could I reach MyEvent::MyEventType value to use it in other modules? I mean doing checks like    (some_int_variable == MyOnEventType).

Comment: They would do `some_int_variable == MyEvent::MyEventType`

Comment: Thank you! :) Debugger shows (via go to break points) that registerEventType call only ones now. It finally work like it should be.

Comment: Also to me it is a big news that we can use class internal field (MyEvent::MyEventType) without using any instanses of that class.

Comment: That's what static member variables are all about. Also, you should accept this answer if it worked for you.

Comment: Thank you. If you remember a good article about static members, please let me know.

Comment: Wow. This was interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337446/is-it-ok-to-use-a-static-variable-to-initalize-register-variables

Comment: Elegant solution.